# Configure docker-compose override to ignore / hide some containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I have (simplified), the following *docker-compose.yml*:

```
parent:
  image: parent
  links:
    - child

child:
  image: child
```

Can I construct a *docker-compose.override.yml* file that will **not** create or start the `child` image?

---

An undesirable (for me) solution, would be to reverse the files, such that the default yml file would create only the `parent`, and the override would create both.

However, I would like the *master* configuration file to contain the most common usage scenario.

Answer (score 23):

In defense of the original poster: I totally get why you would want to do this.
The docker-compose way always seems to be "put your variation in the override files",
but in the interest of keeping things simple within a large development team, I like:

- The ability to start everything with one command (e.g. "docker-compose up" or "docker-compose up main")
- All of my docker definitions in one place

  - The only variation in override files to be which containers are disabled

Here's how I did it in my override files:

```
  # Disable database containers
  postgres:
    image: alpine:latest
    command: "true"
    entrypoint: "true"
  mysql:
    image: alpine:latest
    command: "true"
    entrypoint: "true"
```

The upshot is, all containers are started by "docker-compose up", but those that I've overridden immediately die.

If you want an ever lighter weight container than alpine, try [tianon/true](https://hub.docker.com/r/tianon/true/).

Comment: Best solution that I have found so far.

Comment: Omg, `tianon/true` - `125 bytes total - nothing but "true" (perfect for volume-only containers) Yes, those are "regular bytes" - static assembly for the win.`

Comment: alpine:latest works for me. With tianon/true, I get: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"true\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: @dprothero it works with the following settings in docker-compose.override.yml:
`image: tianon/true` 
`command: ""` 
`entrypoint: ""`

Answer (score 12):

I really like solution from Ryan. But it can be improved.
Create `docker-compose.override.yml` next to `docker-compose.yml` with content:

```
# disable services
version "3"

fluentd:
    image: hello-world
    command: hello
    restart: "no"

elasticsearch:
    image: hello-world
    command: hello
    restart: "no"
```

I believe `hello-world` is a smallest image (size: ~1Kb) on the other hand the size of `alpine` linux is ~6Mb

Comment: Hehe... I'll take your 1Kb and raise you 125b. See `tianon/true` mentioned at the end of my post.

Answer (score 8):

**For versions of compose < 1.28, january 2021**

If you're disabling multiple services in an override file (As in [Ryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45385268/9238801) ), you might find it useful for *Don't-Repeat-Yourself* to make use of [extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#extension-fields), & `yaml` anchors (essentially "back references" in `yaml`).

As in:

```yaml
# Your version
version: "2.4"

# `&anchor-name` defines the anchor (Here it is a map/dict)
# `*anchor-name` references the anchor
# `<<: *anchor-name` merges (`<<:`) the keys of `*anchor-name` with the current map

x-disabled-service: &disabled
  image: "tianon/true"
  command: "true"
  entrypoint: "true"

services:
  elasticsearch:
    <<: *disabled
    
  fluentdb:
    <<: *disabled
```

This uses `tianon/true` as suggested in [Ryan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120260/configure-docker-compose-override-to-ignore-hide-some-containers/45385268#comment99532615_54737675) as a very small image.

The outcome is functionally the same as Ryan, or [Roman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737675/9238801) answers, but a bit less verbose.

**For compose versions >= 1.28**

Also, according to [mcarson's answer to a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65957695/9238801) as of [compose 1.28, January 2021](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1280), there exists a new compose field, `profiles`, which lets you group together containers that can be switched on using a commandline option `--profile`.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/

Comment: I like this solution, `--profile` is elegant and it is built-in the latest docker-compose

Comment: For those people using override files, could you add a `profile` property to unwanted services in a `compose.override.yaml` file and they by default, those with a profile won't be started right?

Comment: @dijonkitchen yep, you can write `profile: NEVER_RUN` for example, and put that in an override, if you want to only sometimes skip the service, you could write it in a file that isnt included by default (ie, not `compose.override.yaml` ), eg `compose.minimal.yaml`, then run like `docker-compose -f compose.yaml -f compose.minimal.yaml up` to only apply the profiles when you want

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to start every service when you run compose, you can just run `up` and pass the names of the services to start. See the official reference for `up` [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).

So for instance: `docker-compose up -d parent`

Comment: right but it's not convenient if you need to start 6-8 containers in a time