# Is there any way to disable a service in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I find myself in the situation, that I want to disable a service temporarily  in a `docker-compose` file.

Of course I could comment it out,  but is there any option to just say "`enabled: false`" ?

Comment: The answer is:  "it depends" ... on what you are trying to accomplish.  If you run `docker-compose up` it will start all the services by default.  However, if you run `docker-compose up myservice` it will start myservice and things that depend on it.  By setting up the dependencies you can make it so the bad service doesn't start with this command.  You can also do `docker-compose run` to get just the services you want.  The right choice may also be to break this into multiple compose files to allow you the flexibility you need.

Comment: In order to handle a similar need I had, I play with [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) and the service argument in [docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/), or the option `--no-deps` in case you don't want to start the dependencies. I know is not what you are looking for, but is the other way around.

Comment: Another option is create as many docker-compose files as you need, and pick which of them you want to include in your calls `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f another-docker-compose.yml up -d`. You can check the resultant docker compose merge with the [config command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/config/): `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f another-docker-compose.yml config`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you define optional docker-compose services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680958/can-you-define-optional-docker-compose-services)

Comment: @EshaanBansal I don't know of such a feature.

Comment: @Mandragor you should switch the accepted answer to the new response from mcarson that uses profiles.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could simply redefine the [`entrypoint` or `command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint) in order to replace said command with something which does nothing  (`/bin/true`)

That would make the container exit immediately, doing nothing.

---

[shadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4126114/shadi) adds the following tips in the comments:

> If you don't want the service to get built at all, redefine the build key to point to a `Dockerfile` that only has:

```
FROM tianon/true 
ENTRYPOINT ["/true"]
```

---

[5andr0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86145/5andr0) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86145/5andr0) the [top-level section `x-disabled:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields) (an extension field-like)

> Far more convenient: moving disabled services to the top-level section `x-disabled:` instead of `services:`
>
> Sections with the `x-` prefix will be parsed, but ignored if not used in the intended way as an extension field.

Comment: I would also add/change `restart: "no"` to avoid infinite restarts

Comment: This does not help in the case that the reason what you want to disable this service is because the service can not even start. In my case, I postgres does not start because there is another instance of postgres running, and the ports command causes conflicts. I could start changing the definition, but at that point commenting the whole thing out is easier.

Comment: Far more convenient: moving disabled services to the top-level section `x-disabled:` instead of `services:`

Comment: @5andr0 Interesting. Is there a documentation for that docker-compose section?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields introduced in v3.4. Sections with the x- prefix will be parsed, but ignored if not used in the intended way as an extension field

Comment: @5andr0 Thank you so much for this follow-up and documentation link. I have included your suggestion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: What about disabling building and loading of images?

Comment: I couldn't find `x-disabled` in documentation. Is it deprecated?

Comment: @Alies The `x-` section is https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#extension, but it is possible indeed that `x-disabled` is no longer valid.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `disabled` part is just a naming convention. Because it will be ignored, it can be any customized name. (Better to go with convention)

Comment: Best answer imo since you can actually just remove the `x-disabled:` line to enable the service, since that makes it in line with the top level `services:` (assuming you add this section directly after the services section.)

Answer (score 252):

As of January 2021, there is a way to elegantly disable a service within the `docker-compose.yml` or to selectively run some services and not others. Docker Compose 1.28.0 introduced support for a `profiles` key. Now we can do something like:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  base_image:
    ...
    profiles:
      - donotstart
```

Examples in the documentation describe how to use this key to create groups of containers that run together based on a `--profile` option on the command line. Check out the page here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/

**Update**

Support for profiles is working correctly in [Compose V2 beta 5](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.5) (`docker compose`). Compose V2 beta 6 has been included in [Docker Desktop 3.5.2](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-352) released 2021-07-08.

Comment: Is there a way to tell docker to _always_ use some profile? like the profile could be "production" vs "development?"

Comment: There is an environment variable that you could set with the name of your default profile. Something like `COMPOSE_PROFILES=production`.

Comment: As of today, has not yet landed in Docker for Mac (which ships with docker-compose 1.27.4)

Comment: This is incredible, and should be the answer for folks using Docker Compose v1.28 and later.

Comment: Note that docker compose version 3.x only works with docker swarm. You cannot use it as standalone on a single machine, like 2.x

Comment: This is great but I can't find any documentation for "default" profiles. I mean, I can set up every profile I want, ok, but where is the "donotstart" specified? Where's the default profile list?

Comment: Found it, there's no such thing as "default" profiles. Simply you are tricking the mechanism by providing a named profile which you won't call later. Right?

Comment: @PatrizioBertoni, that's right. The default is to run containers that have no profile at all. If a container has a profile, it will only be run when you call for that profile. The name I used in my example--"donotstart"--is completely arbitrary. If you want to set a profile to run every time, you can use the `COMPOSE_PROFILES` environment variable. I probably confused things by referring to this earlier as a "default profile."

Answer (score 120):

You can do it in a `docker-compose.override.yaml` file.

This file is automatically read by `docker-compose` and merged into the main `docker-compose.yaml`.

If you have it excluded from Git, each developer can tweak the configuration (with a few limitations) without changing the original `docker-compose.yaml`.

So, service `foo` can be disabled ad-hoc by redefining its entrypoint in `docker-compose.override.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  foo:
    entrypoint: ["echo", "Service foo disabled"]
```

Comment: If you have a "restart: unless-stopped" etc comment out that, or it will continuously restart

Comment: The idea is to change the entrypoint in the override file. If you have restart policies, change it to an infinite sleep loop

Comment: To clarify, you can do this in docker-compose.yml as in VonC's answer.  That would be appropriate if you want to check it in and share it with other developers.
Also, compose file format v1 accepts service names (foo in the example above) as top-level keys, rather than subkeys of "services".

Comment: This solution works nicely if looking to disable/enable a service for a particular environment (eg. development/staging/production) where you have a specified a different override file for each environment with the -f option.

Comment: with docker-compose v3  we can using env for disable service, ie:  `export XXX_ENTRYPOINT=/bin/true`  then ` entrypoint: [ "${XXX_ENTRYPOINT:-docker-entrypoint.sh}"]`

Comment: It's probably better to change command instead of entrypoint. If I set entrypoint to /bin/true, attempt to run it with `docker-compose run` does nothing. but when I set command to /bin/true it does what I need - it exits immediately on `docker-compose up`, but manual start with `docker-compose run` works.

Answer (score 34):

#### assign service to profile(s)

```yaml
services:
  dev_service:
    ...
    profiles: ["dev"] # only runs with dev profile
```

#### enable the profile using

```bash
docker compose --profile dev up
```

ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/

Comment: Holy cow! This is amazing. Can I buy you a coffee for this answer?

Answer (score 19):

I would scale the service to 0 replicas with:

```
deploy:
      replicas: 0
```

Unfortunately as the [documentation states](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#replicas) this **only works with Docker Swarm**.

Comment: "scale: 0" works just fine for me to disable services with a "version: 3.8" docker-compose file and Docker Desktop 3.2.2

Comment: @alv note that "scale" is deprecated

Answer (score 10):

I add the following extra line to the service I want to temporarily disable:

```
command: echo "{put your service name here} disabled"
```

It starts anyway, but does nothing.

Comment: Re-defining the `command` does not have an effect on the entry point. In your example you rely that the `entrypoint` is `bash` I guess. To make this resilient ((independent of the built-in `entrypoint`) I think you need to redefine the entry point, not the command.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to disable a service defined in Docker compose yaml file.
VonC's suggestion is a good workaround
Please see below the docker compose documentation for available options
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score -1):

I got it:

```
docker-compose up $(yq -r '.services | keys | join(" ")' docker-compose.yml | sed 's/service-name//')
```

Comment: This does exactly as I would have expected from the request.  It isn't the easiest to grok, but it works well enough for my case, and I can integrate it into some of my scripts.

Comment: Update for yq version 4: `yq eval '.services | keys | .[] | select(. != "backup")' docker-compose.yml`