# Can you define optional docker-compose services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to define a Docker Compose service such that it is only brought `up` when you explicitly request it?

That is to say:

```
docker-compose up
```

would not start it, but

```
docker-compose up optional_service
```

would.

Comment: Potentially a job for [`extends`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

Comment: Related: Request for adding explicit support for this behavior to Docker Compose: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1896

Comment: To me, you have answered your own question. docker-compose up optional_service doesn't work?

Comment: The problem is that `optional_service` will also start when you invoke `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Docker compose now supports profiles, which allow you to a) disable one or more services by default, and b) enable them when docker compose is ran with the corresponding `--profile` argument.

This is done by adding a `profiles` key to your service in the `docker-compose.yml` file. Services that have don't have this key are always started by docker-compose (for all profiles).

For example, with the following docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.9'
services
  app_service:
    # ...
  test_service:
    profiles:
      - testing
    # ...
```

Running `docker-compose up` will only start the `app_service`, and running `docker-compose --profile testing up` will start both the `app_service` and the `test_service`.

Multiple profiles can be specified by passing multiple `--profile` flags.

More info can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/

Edit: I had to update to docker engine v20.10.5 for this to work.

Answer (score 37):

One way to achieve that is to define your optional service in a different compose file. Then to start the optional service, run:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f optional-service.yaml up
```

For example, if I have a docker-compose.yml file that looks like:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  lb:
    image: nginx:1.13           
  db:
    image: redis:3.2.9
```

I can extend it with an optional-service.yml that looks like:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  busy:
    image: busybox
```

Notice that both compose files must use the same Compose file version.

You can read more about it in the Compose [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

Comment: Would you be able to link those services?

Comment: By default, all services in a Compose project are added to the same network, without needing to link to each other. Run `docker-compose up`, follow by a `docker network ls`. You will see a network named after your Compose project being added. Here's the [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) to Compose Networking.

Comment: Update the command to `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f optional-service.yml up` !

Answer (score 18):

The `extend` keyword has been removed in version `3.x`.

I faced the same issue and this is what I did:

- From Docker's official docs, we can use a [`COMPOSE_FILE`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_file#compose_file) environment variable in a `.env` file.
- The way this works is: when you do `docker-compose up`, instead of reading `docker-compose.yml`, it will read all the compose files specified in `COMPOSE_FILE` variable.

For example,

```
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yml:./optional/docker-compose.prod.yml
```

- the **good part** is that:

  - the `.env` file is auto-read (if located in the same level as `docker-compose.yml`),  when we invoke `docker-compose up`.
  - no need to specify each file with a `-f` flag in CLI.
- The **one drawback** is: need to create separate compose files for each service you wish to make optional.

> Note: separate file names with a `:` in case of linux or `;` in case of windows.