# Programmatically add a service to docker compose project

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have a project with components base on Docker and orchestrated with `docker-compose`. Some of them are optional, and can be added at runtime.

I can think about two ways to achieve that:

- Create a new `serviceA.yml` compose file and run it as a separate project
- Add `serviceA` to my base `compose.yml` and run it again

What is the preferred option to do that?

I've also seen that you can combine `docker-compose` files with the `extend` keyword, but I don't think this can fit, since I have a variable number of services that I can add at runtime.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680958/can-you-define-optional-docker-compose-services/61107015). Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61107015/10534470

Answer (score 8):

I usually end up [having multiple yml files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files).

Then you can add several *-f* flags to *docker-compose* command to indicate which services to run.

For instance, having:

- docker-compose.yml: containing basic services
- docker-compose-additional-services.yml: containing additional/optional services.

You can execute to start:

```
 docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-additional-services.yml up
```

And it will start all services.

Note, that all services are merged as if they were in a single file, so you can reference (*depends_on*, *link*) services from one file to the other.

Comment: We use the same technique. We have a main compose file with our core services and a `monitoring.yml` for our ELK stack, datadog alerting, etc. It's worked well.