# Docker - in docker-compose.override.yml, prevent a service being executed or immediately stop the service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use the [docker-compose.override.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) to override my docker services in development and specifically reference the `docker-compose.yml` file when deploying to more production like environments much like [this workflow](https://medium.com/@basi/docker-compose-from-development-to-production-88000124a57c).

If I have a service say `my-job-scheduler`, I don't want that to run in development so would prefer to include something in my `docker-compose.override.yml` file that tells `docker-compose`:

- Dont start this service; or
- Immediately stop this service

Is there a good pattern to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of a single simple `command` such as `echo` and flagging `restart` as `"no"`:

```
services: 
  my-job-scheduler: 
    command: echo "do nothing"
    restart: "no"
```

Comment: Looks like this can be combined with the ultra-light 'tianon/true' image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37255042/93345 , https://hub.docker.com/r/tianon/true/ to minimize the time wasted in starting up a suppressed service.