# Prevent container startup

Tags: docker-compose

I have this docker compose:

```
  myservice:
    restart: "no"
```

With `no` the service will start anyway (but it won't restart)

How can I prevent the service to start at all?

Note: the reason I want to do this, for those curious, is that I want to make this flag configurable via an env var:

```
  myservice:
    restart: "${RESTART_SERVICE:-no}"
```

And then pass the right value to start the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Docker provides restart policies to control whether your containers start automatically when they exit, or when Docker restart.
>
> - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

So it's only when containers exit or when Docker restart.

But you have two options for what you want to do:

First only start the service you want:

```sh
docker-compose up other-service
```

This don't use ENV as you want (unless you have a script for run the docker-compose up ).

```sh
if [[ $START == true ]]; then
  docker-compose up
else
  docker-compose up other-service
fi
```

But as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54214179/12962618) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37255042/12962618), you can overwrite the `entrypoint`

So you can do something like:

```yaml
services:
  alpine:
    image: alpine:latest
    environment:
      - START=false
    volumes:
      - ./start.sh:/start.sh
    entrypoint: ['sh', '/start.sh']
```

And and start.sh like:

```sh
if [ $START == true ]; then
  echo ok # replace with the original entrypoint or command
else
  exit 0
fi
```

```sh
# START=false in the docker-compose
$ docker-compose up 
Starting stk_alpine_1 ... done
Attaching to stk_alpine_1
stk_alpine_1 exited with code 0

$ sed -i 's/START=false/START=true/' docker-compose.yml 

$ docker-compose up 
Starting stk_alpine_1 ... done
Attaching to stk_alpine_1
alpine_1  | ok
stk_alpine_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: I went for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37255042/647991) idea, but yours is also valid.